# Why did "Curb" change from being shot on video to being shot on film?

Tags: seinfeld, curb-your-enthusiasm

Why did they do that? I know *Curb Your Enthusiasm* was a slow motion frame rate video until like 2009 or 2010. Why the change?

Comment: Your question about the shift from video to film is perfectly reasonable, but I don't understand the part about 'slow motion frame rate'.  NTSC video is 30fps (PAL in Europe is 25fps) whereas most film recording is 24fps.  There's nothing 'slow' about video when compared to film.

Comment: In this and your Seinfeld, DS9 questions ... are you actually talking about frame resolution rather than frame rate?  Old Seinfeld and old Curb being in standard rather than high definition?

Comment: I'm tentatively going to close this as a duplicate as it has already been asked before.  If I've misunderstood, please ping me and perhaps we can clarify what you are looking for.